# Session variables not being display on particular page

Tags: php

I'm not a PHP developer here.

I have a page that is unable to display session values even though they definitely exist. I am able to view them on another page, yet for some reason they cannot be seen on a certain page!?

EDIT:
Below is the script that exists on the top of the page

```
<?php
    require_once('eu_gl.php'); // <- includes session_start() in it
    if(!session_id()) session_start(); // added this in case, but should not be needed
?>
```

Contents of the include:

```
<?php
/*** Global include file **/

set_time_limit(300);
$time1 = microtime();

define('APP_SESS_NAME', 'EURA');
session_name(APP_SESS_NAME);
session_start();
session_set_cookie_params(0);
//...
?>
```

Comment: is there `session_start()` on that page?

Comment: Yes it exists in an include file that is called using require()

Comment: You're going to have to show us what you're doing, both where you set the variables and when you attempt to retrieve them. Make a testcase.

Comment: @Chev: [Making a testcase](http://sscce.org/) is the only way that this question will get answered. Is that enough "to do with the question" for you?

Comment: Think I have figured out the issue: seems the naming of the session was the issue. If it was named in the include: session_name(APP_SESS_NAME), then it seems I have to use that session name when starting it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the naming of the session was the issue. Tt was named in the include: session_name(APP_SESS_NAME), then it seems I have to use that session name when starting it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As @k102 mentioned, ensure you have `session_start();` somewhere before you set/get your session variables.  `print_r($_SESSION);` can also be handy in showing you what session information exists ...

I personally would modify your code to have this:

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

 if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
      $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
 } else {
      $_SESSION['count']++;
 }

 print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: session_start() exists in an include file that is called using require() They values are there and being set correctly, just cannot view them on this page. Difference being that on this page session_start() is called in an include file and that seems to be the issue?

Comment: sorry, but i think this has to be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @k102: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @Chev: "I won't show you code, but I'll tell you about it. OK, so, this is what my code does: nothing wrong. What's wrong?"

Comment: @Chev: Why? I'm trying to demonstrate to you the futility of annotation-over-demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

**First point** is :
better try

```
 if(session_id() == "" ) session_start();
```

instead of

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();
```

as session_id wont return false.

php manual:

> session_id() returns the session id for the current session or the
>   empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session
>   id exists).

**Second point** is that session_start shall be the very first thing on your page unless you really need sthg else, but I can't see any reason in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 php file for checking $_SESSION, session used for storing variable so you can use it in all page of your website.

test.php:

```
set_time_limit(300); // Timeout for script
$time1 = microtime(); // What this variable do in your script
define('APP_SESS_NAME', 'EURA'); // set constant APP_SESS_NAME
session_name(APP_SESS_NAME); // name session APP_SESS_NAME
session_start(); // start session
session_set_cookie_params(0); // this line must be called before session_start();

if(!session_id()) session_start(); // Delete this line

$_SESSION['name']= "test"; // set variable session with params name for checking session
```

test2.php:

```
define('APP_SESS_NAME', 'EURA'); // set constant APP_SESS_NAME
session_name(APP_SESS_NAME); // name session APP_SESS_NAME
session_start(); // start session
echo $_SESSION['name']; // check session is valid
```

I think you should understand about Session now.